# ASP.NET MVC: Download stream without freezing

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-blob-storage

We use ASP.NET MVC 4 (Presentation), WCF (Logic), Azure Blob Storage (Storage).

Is it possible to implement stream-downloading (pass through) without freezing navigation on web-site?

We exactly need "passing through" because custom headers are required (Content-Disposition etc). It means that FilePathResult and direct link to Azure are not possible.

Downloading is implemented by this way now:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadTemplate(Guid templateId)
{
    Response.Clear(); Response.BufferOutput = false;

    DownloadResult result = Client.DownloadTemplate(templateId)

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", MimeHelper.GetMimeType(result.FileName));
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + result.FileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; int readed = 0;

    while ((readed = result.ContentStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readed);
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Maybe with [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: As I know all descendants of FileResult are buffering output and waiting for action complete too, seems like IHttpHandler is required or something like this, but as I undestand IHttpHandler can serve only one request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding proxy WCF rest file service between storage abstraction and browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your button should make a javascript ajax call to your web method in a controller..

Comment: How do you imagine it? Can you explain?

Comment: Modify the relevant button to have an onclick='$.get("url");' Make sure that when you generate the view.. the guid is on the end of the url.. that leads straight to your method.  Since you are in MVC, you have JQuery available.. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: The result of $.get is jqXHR it means that file will be fetched but its impossible to save it from javascript to client file system

Comment: The result of the Ajax request.. assuming you have the right headers on your response, should result in an automatic file download.. to the client's file system.  There isn't any other behavior possible.

Comment: Thanks, resolved by adding proxy rest file service. Didn't find another ways.